# Remove a parameter from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string:

```
orderby=alphabetical&page=3
```

but it can be even like this:

```
orderby=alphabetical&other=param&page=1234
```

What I want to do is to delete from that string the paramater `&page=[Number]`
in such a way to have the following string:

```
orderby=alphabetical&other=param
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I tried this: re.sub('&page=', '', string) but I don't know to remove the number

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service!

Comment: So you have *URL parameters*. Have you tried the available Python tools for handling such parameters? You could parse, delete the key from the Python structure, then re-encode, for example.

Comment: @Kasra: don't use a custom entry when 'too broad' or 'unclear' would do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Its too clear but maybe using *too broad* was a good choice!

Comment: Get the `&page=` first char's index, then use it to slice the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`parse.parse_qsl`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl) to decompose the param string into a list of name/value pairs. Then use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out any name/value pair for which `name` equals `'page'`. Finally, rebuild the param string using [`parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
import urllib.parse as parse

paramstr = 'orderby=alphabetical&other=param&page=1234'
params = parse.parse_qsl(paramstr)
params = [(name, val) for name, val in params if name != 'page']
print(parse.urlencode(params))
```

yields

```
orderby=alphabetical&other=param
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
url = 'orderby=alphabetical&other=param&page=1234'
params = url.split('&')
print('&'.join(i for i in params if 'page=' not in i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> newstring=string[0:string.find("&page")]
>>> print newstring
orderby=alphabetical
```

Comment: This works if `page` is always the last URL parameter in the string. While that's the case in both examples given in the question, it's unclear from the question whether this assumption can be made generally.